# Replacing characters in a string loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a template txt file. This txt file is to be written as 10 new files but each with some characters changed according to a list of arbitrary values:

```
with open('template.txt') as template_file:
     template = template_file.readlines()
     for i in range(10):
          with open('output_%s.txt' % i, 'w') as new_file:
               new_file.writelines(template_file)
```

The length of the list is the same as the number of new files (10).

I am trying to replace part of the 2nd line of each new file with the value in my list.

So for example, I want line 2, positions [5:16] in each new file replaced with the respective value in the list..

File 0 will have element 0 of the list 
File 1 will have element 1 of the list
etc..

I tried using the `replace()` method:

```
list = [element0, element1, etc...element9]

for i in template_file:
    i.replace(template_file[2][5:16], list_element)
```

But it will only replace all the files with the first list element... It wont loop over.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Where does `list_element` come from?

Comment: from the list...  I know it's not right.. thats where the issue is... I want each element in 'list' (i.e list_element) to replace characters in each iteration of new txt file

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems I can find which prevent your code from working:

- You should write `template` out, which is a list of lines, not `template_file`, which is a file object
- In Python, strings are immutable, meaning they cannot be changed. The `replace` function does not change the string, it returns a new copy of the string. Furthermore, `replace` will replace a substring with a new text, regardless of where that substring is. If you want to replace at a specific index, I suggest to slice the string yourself. For example:

  ```
  line2 = '0123456789ABCDEFG'
  element = '-ho-ho-ho-'
  line2 = line2[:5] + element + line2[16:]
  # line2 now is '01234-ho-ho-ho-G'
  ```
- Please do not use `list` as a variable name. It is a type, which can be used to construct a new list as such:

  ```
  empty = list()         # ==> []
  letters = list('abc')  # ==> ['a', 'b', 'c']
  ```
- The expression `template_file[2][5:16]` is incorrect: First, it should be `template`, not `template_file`. Second, the second line should be `template[1]`, not `template[2]` since Python list are zero based
- The `list_element` variable is not declared in your code

## Solution 1

That being said, I find that it is easier to structure your template file as a real template with placeholders. I'll talk about that later. If you still insist to replace index 5-16 of line 2 with something, here is a solution I tested and it works:

```
with open('template.txt') as template_file:
    template = template_file.readlines()
    elements = ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'JKL']
    for i, element in enumerate(elements):
        with open('output_%02d.txt' % i, 'w') as out_file:
            line2 = template[1]
            line2 = line2[:5] + element + line2[16:]
            for line_number, line in enumerate(template, 1):
                if line_number == 2:
                    line = line2
                out_file.write(line)
```

Notes

- The code writes out all lines, but with special replacement applies to line 2
- The code is clunky, nested deeply
- I don't like having to hard code the index numbers (5, 16) because if the template changes, I have to change the code as well

## Solution 2

If you have control of the template file, I suggest to use the `string.Template` class to make search and replace easier. Since I don't know what your template file looks like, I am going to make up my own template file:

```
line #1
This is my ${token} to be replaced
line #3
line #4
```

Note that I intent to replace `${token}` with one of the elements in the code. Now on to the code:

```
import string

with open('template.txt') as template_file:
    template = string.Template(template_file.read())
    elements = ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'JKL']
    for i, element in enumerate(elements):
        with open('output_%02d.txt' % i, 'w') as out_file:
            out_file.write(template.substitute(token=element))
```

Notes

- I read the whole file in at once with `template_file.read()`. This could be a problem if the template file is large, but previous solution als ran into the same performance issue as this one
- I use the `string.Template` class to make search/replace easier
- Search and replace is done by `substitute(token=element)` which said: replace all the `$token` or `${token}` instances in the `template` with `element`.
- The code is much cleaner and dare I say, easier to read.

## Solution 3

If the template file is too large to fit in memory at once, you can modify the first solution to read it line-by-line instead of reading all lines in at once. I am not going to present that solution here, just a asuggestion.

Comment: Thank you very much for your eloquent answer. I think solution 2 is the best way to go about it for my needs. Looks like a very useful library. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need

```
list = [element0, element1, etc...element9]
for i in list:
    template_file = template_file.replace(template_file[2][5:16], i)
```